# Como criar o evento para uma textbox em runtime?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

```
foreach (SobralFoodContext.Produto produtos in categoria)
{
    string str = "<div class=\"col-sm-4\"><div class=\"card\"><div class=\"pricing-list dark-pricing\"><div class=\"prc-head\"><h4>" + produtos.Nome + "</h4></div><div class=\"prc-list\"><ul><li><a>"+produtos.Preco+"€</a></li><li><a>"+produtos.Detalhes+ "</a></li><asp:textbox Text=\"1\" width=\"30px\" ID=\"txt" + produtos.IdProduto.ToString() + "\"  runat=\"server\"></asp:textbox></ul><asp:LinkButton runat=\"server\" OnClick=\"AddCar_Click\"  ID=\"Add_" + produtos.IdProduto.ToString() + "\" >Adicionar Ao Carrinho</asp:LinkButton></div></div></div></div>";
     Control c = ParseControl(str);
    Entradas_table.Controls.Add(c);
    ((LinkButton)Entradas_table.FindControl("Add_" + produtos.IdProduto.ToString())).Command += new CommandEventHandler(AddCar_Click);
    ((TextBox)Entradas_table.FindControl("txt" + produtos.IdProduto.ToString())).Text += new EventHandler(AddCar_Click);

    //((LinkButton)produtos_table.FindControl("Remove_" + funcionario.IdFuncionario.ToString())).Command += new CommandEventHandler(btEliminar_Click);

}

protected void AddCar_Click (object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    LinkButton botao = (LinkButton)sender;
    TextBox texto =(TextBox)sender;

    int produtoid = int.Parse(botao.ID.Split('_')[1]);
    float z;
    var produto = (from x in context.Produtos
                   where x.IdProduto == produtoid
                   select x).SingleOrDefault();


    z = float.Parse(produto.Preco);

   Faturas.adiciona(produto.IdProduto, produto.Nome, z,texto.Text);
}
```

Queria saber como chamo a `TextBox` para o evento `AddCar_Click`.

Comment: O evento `AddCar_Click` funciona? Porque o `sender` só pode ser de um tipo, ou `LinkButton` ou `TextBox`.

Comment: so funcionar com um dos dois. como é que eu meto para ficar a funcionar para os dois? isso é que eu não compreendo